# directive with isolate scope not updating template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to understand how isolate scopes work, and am obviously missing something very basic. 
I am trying to set a scope property via a select box and then pass this property into a directive's isolate scope, but it doesn't seem to be working right.

Here's an example that summarizes my problem: 
[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/SPMfT/160/)
The view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <select name='optionfoo' ng-model='foo'>
       <option>a</option>
       <option>b</option>
    </select>
    value: {{foo}}
    <div id='dir' isolate_foo="{{foo}}" dir></div>
    <div id='dir2' foo="{{foo}}" dir2></div>
</div>
```

The js code:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
    .directive('dir', function () {
        return {
            restrict:'A',
            template: 'isolate foo: {{foo}}',
            scope:{               
                foo:'@isolate_foo',
            }        
        };
    }).directive('dir2', function () {
        return {
            restrict:'A',
            template: 'parent foo:{{foo}}', 
        };
    })
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.foo = 'b';
    }]);
```

In the example, I have two directives - one that tries to pull in a property via isolate scope, and one that just inherits the parent scope. the 'dir2' directive seems to work as expected, whereas the 'dir' directive (the isolate scope directive) seems to actually unset the attribute that is being passed in the parent directive.

I'm sure this is a noob question, but i've spent hours searching and haven't figured out what i'm doing wrong. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of naming convention. Replace

```
scope: {               
  foo:'@isolate_foo',
}
```

with

```
scope: {               
  foo:'@isolateFoo',
}
```

and it will work. Here's your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SPMfT/164/) with that fix applied.

The explanation for that is in the [Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> Directives have camel cased names such as ngBind. The directive can be
>   invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these
>   special characters :, -, or _.

So if you define the markup as `isolate_foo`, Angular will, by design, map its value to a property named `isolateFoo` in the directive's scope.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/roadprophet/SPMfT/161/

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
    .directive('dir', function () {
        return {
            restrict:'A',
            template: 'isolate foo: {{foo}}',
            scope:{               
                foo:'@',
            }        
        };
    }).directive('dir2', function () {
        return {
            restrict:'A',
            template: 'parent foo:{{foo}}', 
        };
    })
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.foo = 'b';
    }]);
```

**EDIT**

Here is a clarifying version of your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/roadprophet/SPMfT/163/

Comment: "@ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are strings. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given <widget my-attr="hello {{name}}"> and widget definition of scope: { localName:'@myAttr' }, then widget scope property localName will reflect the interpolated value of hello {{name}}. As the name attribute changes so will the localName property on the widget scope. The name is read from the parent scope (not component scope)."

Comment: from http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive explains that you are binding to the attribute 'foo' of the custom directive.  So when the expression {{foo}} changes because the controller scope changes due to the select binding, the attribute binding updates the  dir1's foo bound to the attribute.  That make sense?